# RCPP error: undefined symbol: _ZTIN4Rcpp7RObjectE on package install

Tags: r, zlib, rcpp

Using the default hello world program through Rcpp.package.skeleton I 'sometimes' get this error on install.

Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/usrname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/helloWorld/libs/helloWorld.so': /home/usrname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/helloWorld/libs/helloWorld.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN4Rcpp7RObjectE.

By sometimes I mean, in about 10 tries only once did it get that error on the first time installing although in the end after some tweaks every package eventually gets the error and even if all changes are removed from the code and all the .o,.so and the tar file deleted, and the library uninstalled in R, the package will not build again.

My end goal is to include some zlib functions into some code using the -lz compile option so when I say 'some tweaks' to the hello_world they would be:
1. add -lz to the PKG_LIBS var in Makevars
2. Add #include  to the .cpp file
3. Create a const char* a
4. attempt to use a to call gzopen(a,a)

My process is 
1. in R: Rcpp.package.skeleton("testPackage", attributes = TRUE)
2. in terminal: R CMD build testPackage
3. in terminal: R CMD INSTALL testPackage

Just to test one last time, I compiled okay, I added the -lz and it was okay, then I added #include  and I get the error.  I remove it and still get the error.

So: 
1. Does anyone know what is causing this error? 
2. Is there away to repair it so that reverted code installs again? 
3. If not, is there another way to build zlib into code (sourceCpp seems to work fine).

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 
R version 3.01 
Rcpp_0.10.3

Update with solution: 
When editing Makevars I was inadvertently adding an extra set of quotes around the variable as such: 
PKG_LIBS = "`$/usr/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` -lz" 
The correct way to include zlib is to just append -lz to the line: 
PKG_LIBS = `$/usr/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` -lz 
It still remains true that once you get the error, if you try to revert Makevars back to the correct format, you will continue to get the error on install.  And it also remains true that sometimes (2/6 from my test runs) it will install with the error only to later pop up when including  or adding zlib functions into the code.

Answer (score 3):

My RcppCNPy package uses zlib. It uses

```
 PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` -lz
```

and has code as eg

```
cnpy::NpyArray cnpy::npy_gzload(std::string fname) {
    gzFile fp = gzopen(fname.c_str(), "rb");
    if(!fp) {
        Rf_error("npy_gzload: Error! Unable to open file %s!\n",fname.c_str());
    }
    NpyArray arr = gzload_the_npy_file(fp);
    gzclose(fp);
    return arr;
}
```

Maybe this can serve as a model for you.

Comment: Item 1 on my changelist was modifying the Makevars file in the package to include -lz as you've mentioned.  The first few times this was the trigger for the error.  But at least once I added it and it compiled and then on one of the remaining changes it errored out.  But I can assume then that adding -lz to PKG_LIBS has worked for someone to allow use of the zlib functions (the first time I compiled my code with that argument, I was seeing an error something to the effect of 'gzopen' undefined since then I get the aforementioned error before I can even get a normal compile error)

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say here.  If you could clarify your post with a _reproducible_ example I may be able to help.

Comment: I was trying to make a test log but I uncovered the rather simple answer and will update the post.  It may be worth still noting that with my mistake it 'sometimes' caused the error and sometimes allowed a few changes and reinstalls before creating the error.  In addition, I still have the issue where once the error is created you cannot revert back and install but that may be a moot point.